# What does “that sticks” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does “that sticks” mean in the following line?

> What is the most resilient parasite? Bacteria? A virus? An intestinal worm? An idea. Resilient. . . highly contagious. Once an idea has taken hold of the brain it's almost impossible to eradicate. An idea that is fully formed, fully understood. . . **that sticks** right in there somewhere.
> <sub>Source: [IMDB, Quotes for Dominic Cobb (Character) from *Inception* (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0162705/quotes)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Stick" as an intransitive verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick) (scroll down to Definition #2):

1. to remain in a place, situation, or environment
2. to hold fast or adhere resolutely; cling
3. to remain effective

Similar to how a "sticky note" can be used to keep an idea in 1 place on paper, the sentence means that the complete, understood idea manages to remain in your brain.

Or, perhaps that it's a good enough, complete enough, and clear enough idea to stick around over time.

Comment: +1 I think it might help the OP even better if it's pointed out that the OP's example is not a complete sentence.

Comment: I’ve updated the question to include the full quote. I think it would help to mention that that “that” refers back to the subject “idea”.

Comment: Had no idea it was a quote ... Will edit this later to clarify. Good catch!